# Diferenças entre Success e Then AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

Até agora tenho utilizado o `success` para as `Http Promises`.

Ex:

```
$http.get(/url).success(function(data){
     console.log("Sucesso");
    })
    .error(function(response, status) {
      console.log("erro " + status);
    });
  }
```

Porém hoje encontrei um exemplo onde o `success` pode ser substituído por `then`:

```
$http.get(/url).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log("Sucesso");
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log("Erro: "+response);
  });
```

Gostaria de saber quais são as diferenças entre essas duas `promisses` e quais as vantagens de utiliza-las.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a

Comment: Você não sabe realmente a intenção do `stackoverflow` @PauloHDSousa?

Comment: PRA MIM é ajudar os outros a resolver problemas de programação

Comment: Sempre quis saber isso também @Techies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Os métodos `success` e `error` são a maneira antiga para se processar as *promises* para os casos de sucesso e erro resultantes do *provider* `$http`.

Eles fazem a mesma coisa que o método `then()` e seus dois parâmetros de *callback*.

Adicionalmente, os métodos *success* e *error* estão agora marcados como *deprecated*:

> The $http legacy promise methods *success* and *error* have been deprecated. Use the standard *then* method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Portanto utilize `then()`, ou escreva callbacks diretos.

Fonte: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http